# Autocompletion in CEDET?

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs24, emacs-ecb

I'm trying to set up CEDET 2.2 in Emacs 24.3 to provide me with autocompletion, using ["A gentle introduction to cedet"](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html), but it doesn't exactly want to work the way I want it to.

First, I tried to use CEDET's own completion, but that one doesn't provide a "popup menu", only the first completion it can find, and there's no way to cycle through. Then I installed auto-complete with packages and set it up as it's described on [the page](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html). That also doesn't work - auto-complete crashes saying `auto-complete error: (void-variable ac-source-semantic)`. The same goes for ac-source-gtags.

Is that just not possible because of the buggy CEDET at the moment, or did I misconfigure it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configuring CEDET is a massive pain (it took me months to get jump-to-definition and auto completion working in an existing project).

So you certainly might have misconfigured CEDET as it's hard to get right, I'll leave my config here for you to look through, but it really depends on your project and is stupidly finicky.

```lisp
(setq cedet-root-path (file-name-as-directory "~/.emacs.d/lisp/cedet-bzr/trunk/"))

(load-file (concat cedet-root-path "cedet-devel-load.el"))
(add-to-list 'load-path (concat cedet-root-path "contrib"))

;; select which submodes we want to activate
(mapc (lambda (MODE) (add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes MODE))
      '(global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode
        global-semanticdb-minor-mode
        global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode
        global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode
        global-cedet-m3-minor-mode
        global-semantic-highlight-func-mode
        global-semanticdb-minor-mode))

;; Activate semantic
(semantic-mode 1)

;; load contrib library
(require 'eassist)

;; customisation of modes
(mapc
 (lambda (MODE)
   (add-hook MODE
             (lambda ()
               (when (boundp 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol) (add-to-list 'completion-at-point-functions 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol))
               (local-set-key [(control return)] 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu)
               (local-set-key "\C-c?" 'semantic-ia-complete-symbol)
               (local-set-key "\C-c>" 'semantic-complete-analyze-inline)
               (local-set-key "\C-c=" 'semantic-decoration-include-visit)
               (local-set-key "\C-cj" 'semantic-ia-fast-jump)
               (local-set-key "\C-cq" 'semantic-ia-show-doc)
               (local-set-key "\C-cs" 'semantic-ia-show-summary)
               (local-set-key "\C-cp" 'semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle)
               ))) '(c-mode-common-hook lisp-mode-hook emacs-lisp-mode-hook))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook (lambda ()
                                (local-set-key "\C-ct" 'eassist-switch-h-cpp)
                                (local-set-key "\C-xt" 'eassist-switch-h-cpp)
                                (local-set-key "\C-ce" 'eassist-list-methods)
                                (local-set-key "\C-c\C-r" 'semantic-symref)))

(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode t)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode t)

(when (cedet-ectag-version-check t)
  (semantic-load-enable-primary-ectags-support))

;; SRecode
(global-srecode-minor-mode 1)

;; EDE
(global-ede-mode 1)
(ede-enable-generic-projects)

(defun qt-cedet-setup ()
  "Set up c-mode and related modes. Includes support for Qt code (signal, slots and alikes)."

  ;; add knowledge of qt to emacs
  (setq qt4-base-dir (concat (getenv "QTDIR") "/include"))
  (semantic-add-system-include (concat qt4-base-dir "/Qt") 'c++-mode)
  (semantic-add-system-include (concat qt4-base-dir "/QtGui") 'c++-mode)
  (semantic-add-system-include (concat qt4-base-dir "/QtCore") 'c++-mode)
  (semantic-add-system-include (concat qt4-base-dir "/QtTest") 'c++-mode)
  (semantic-add-system-include (concat qt4-base-dir "/QtNetwork") 'c++-mode)
  (semantic-add-system-include (concat qt4-base-dir "/QtSvg") 'c++-mode)
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist (cons qt4-base-dir 'c++-mode))
  (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file (concat qt4-base-dir "/Qt/qconfig.h"))
  (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file (concat qt4-base-dir "/Qt/qconfig-large.h"))
  (add-to-list 'semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file (concat qt4-base-dir "/Qt/qglobal.h"))

  ;; qt keywords and stuff ...
  ;; set up indenting correctly for new qt kewords
  (setq c-protection-key (concat "\\<\\(public\\|public slot\\|protected"
                                 "\\|protected slot\\|private\\|private slot"
                                 "\\)\\>")
        c-C++-access-key (concat "\\<\\(signals\\|public\\|protected\\|private"
                                 "\\|public slots\\|protected slots\\|private slots"
                                 "\\)\\>[ \t]*:"))

  ;; modify the colour of slots to match public, private, etc ...
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode '(("\\<\\(slots\\|signals\\)\\>" . font-lock-type-face)))
  ;; make new font for rest of qt keywords
  (make-face 'qt-keywords-face)
  (set-face-foreground 'qt-keywords-face "BlueViolet")
  ;; qt keywords
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode '(("\\<Q_[A-Z]*\\>" . 'qt-keywords-face)))
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode '(("\\<SIGNAL\\|SLOT\\>" . 'qt-keywords-face)))
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode '(("\\<Q[A-Z][A-Za-z]*\\>" . 'qt-keywords-face)))
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode '(("\\<Q[A-Z_]+\\>" . 'qt-keywords-face)))
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode
                          '(("\\<q\\(Debug\\|Wait\\|Printable\\|Max\\|Min\\|Bound\\)\\>" . 'font-lock-builtin-face)))

  (setq c-macro-names-with-semicolon '("Q_OBJECT" "Q_PROPERTY" "Q_DECLARE" "Q_ENUMS"))
  (c-make-macro-with-semi-re)
  )
(when (getenv "QTDIR") (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'qt-cedet-setup))
```

Comment: What's emacs version do you use?

Comment: When I wrote this I was using 23.something, now I'm using 24.3.1